# Bash Script if else not working

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting and I have encountered a problem that I quite don't understand how to slove it.
These are my codes:

```
n=$1
e=$2
echo "$n"
if [$e -eq 1]
then
    echo "$n done"
    echo "$e"
else
    echo "$n done only"
fi
```

If I run the script as
    `./programName hello 1`
The problem occurs as

```
./programName: line 6: [1: command not found
```

Only the else part runs after the first echo has been executed.
I have tried starting the script in these ways:

- `./programName hello 1`
- `./programName hello -e 1`
- `./programName -n hello -e 1`

While the first and second gives the same error as above. The third doesn't execute the first *echo* and gives the *echo* of the *else* part as `-e done only`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You need to use space after [  and before ] like this:
if [ $e -eq 1 ]
Plus, use double quotes around $e like this "$e"

Comment: btw: `[`  is a synonym for the "test" builtin command. [ is actually a command. So, that's why you need to use space after `[`